# CActiveRecord Iteration not respected Virtual Attributes

Tags: php, object, yii

i have a model extended from [CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord)
let says the name of the class is `SomeModel` and the object is `$foo`

```
$foo = SomeModel::model()->findByPk(1);
```

Then i created virtual attributes on that model

```
$foo->setImage('testing.jpg');
```

When i testing call the property/state it works perfectly:

```
var_dump($foo->image); // output testing.jpg
```

But when i do iteration with the model it didn't show the property.

```
foreach($foo as $key => $value) {
        echo $key .' = '. $value."\n";
    }
```

How to make the `image` property listed when i do iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't iterate a model like that. Try this instead:

```
foreach ( $foo->getAttributes() as $key => $value ) {
    //  Do stuff
}
```

Comment: is there any reason why i can't iterate model like that? cause if i do that, it's yes output the property from the field of database, but not the property i created manually/virtual

Comment: Mainly, the CActiveRecord class wasn't created as an iterator/traversable object. So until that happens, you have to do the above.